# What does this line mean "dat <- data.frame(obsnames = row.names(PC$x), PC$x)"?

Tags: r, pca, bioconductor

I'm looking into the sourcecode of a function in R and part of it is this:

```
dat <- data.frame(obsnames = row.names(PC$x), PC$x)
```

As far as I know you can assign one column as row.names, so the second PC$x doesn't make sense to me. Any idea?

I get the sourcecode using this:

```
library(cummeRbund)
showMethods(PCAplot)
getMethod("PCAplot","CuffData")
```

The commands above returns [THIS](http://textuploader.com/5ezcn) text.

Any help it's appreciated.

Comment: Try `data.frame(obsnames = row.names(mtcars), mtcars$mpg)` and see what it is doing with sample data. It is essentially `cbind`ing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whole idea of the statement is to convert `rownames` into one of the columns of a `dataframe` and append it to the actual data.

Point to Note: `rownames(any_object)` is not a column in the data frame.

I. Creating data frame `df` with one column 'Data`

```
   df <- data.frame(Data = c("Stack","OverFLow","Stack","EXchange"))
   df
   #       Data
   # 1    Stack
   # 2 OverFLow
   # 3    Stack
   # 4 EXchange
```

II. Converting `rownames` of `df` into a column and binding it to `Data` column of `df` and storing it to new data frame `df1`

To convert `rownames` into one of the columns of a data frame, it is just creating a new data frame `df1` where your `first column` is `row names` and `second column` is the actual first column of your old data.

```
   df1 <- data.frame(obsnames = rownames(df),df$Data)
   df1
   #    obsnames  df.Data
   # 1         1    Stack
   # 2         2 OverFLow
   # 3         3    Stack
   # 4         4 EXchange
```

III. Changing `rownames` of a data frame

If you want to change `rownames` of any data frame, here it would go like this

```
    rownames(df1) <- c("first","second","third","fourth")
    df1
    #         obsnames  df.Data
    # first          1    Stack
    # second         2 OverFLow
    # third          3    Stack
    # fourth         4 EXchange
```

IV. To bind `rownames` to whole `dataframe`

```
df <- data.frame(AA = 31:33, BB = 21:23, CC = 11:13, DD = 1:3)
df
#   AA BB CC DD
# 1 31 21 11  1
# 2 32 22 12  2
# 3 33 23 13  3

df1 <- data.frame(obsnames = rownames(df),df)
df1
#    obsnames AA BB CC DD
# 1         1 31 21 11  1
# 2         2 32 22 12  2
# 3         3 33 23 13  3
```

Comment: thank you very much, this really help me figure out what I was trying to do

Comment: Great!! Thank you.